# Odoo - Call many function with action server

Tags: odoo

I would like to call many existing functions like action_confirm () from the server action without going through development. It's possible ? Can you help me ?

Thank you !

EDIT :

I managed to do this following method :

```
        if records:
            action = records.print_quotation()
            for record in records:
                record.message_post(body="1")
                record.message_post(body=records)
                record.message_post(body=record)
                #record.print_quotation()
                record.message_post(body="Lien bon de commande")
                record.action_confirm()
                # record.message_post(body="MESSAGE TEST ON LOGGER")
                # record.message_post(body=record.action_confirm())
```

But I don't understand why action_confirm is in a loop and print_quotation is declare via action =. It works but I don't quite understand the logic. If I reverse the roles it doesn't work

Comment: Of course, just call `record.your_method()`, It will call your method on the record on which the action is triggered; may be void.  Check the Odoo server actions for examples under `Technical > Actions >   Server Actions`

Comment: Thanks. For example, I am in the "Sales" module. I added a button via an Odoo view to the Sale form. This button, I managed to link it to a server action. I'm trying to call the method to print -> print_quotation () and it works. While I call the action_confirm () method to confirm the sale, and I got an error. I do not understand why.

Comment: Show the error log, it may be helpful

Comment: Here is what I put :    action = records.action_confirm()
Here error :  ValueError: <class 'AttributeError'>: "'sale.order' object has no attribute 'action_confim'" while evaluating
'records.action_confim()'

Comment: Change the method name to ``action_confirm``

Comment: Thanks. New error :   File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 311, in clean_action
    action.setdefault('flags', {})
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setdefault'. 
I don't understand. However, with debug mode, I see that the print button which has the print_quotation() method and the sale confirmation button which has the action_confirm() method are part of the sale.order pattern.

Comment: The print action is returning something the client (browser) has to handle, where the confirm action does return some values, the client don't have to handle at all, but could if wanted. So setting the variable `action` in a server action will use the value as final action to do by the client. If you just call the print action, without telling the client anything, nothing would be printed.

Comment: @PseudoWithK Odoo expects an [action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/developer/reference/actions.html), and you probably assigned the action to the result of [action_confirm](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L787) method, which is a ``boolean``. To confirm orders, you can simply use `records.action_confirm()`.  I can see that `acttion_confirm` is done at the end after posting some messages, Maybe that's the reason they did this. If you call `action_cofirm` twice the second time, it will raise an error because it is already in `done` state (last line).